# How can I see a github user's most recent public commits?

Tags: github

I follow a number of github users and wonder if there is a way to view all of their recent commits.

Not just on a single repo basis but across all repos. A way to see all their public contributions by date.

I've searched for previous answers but they appear to be inappropriate or out of date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to a user's GitHub page.

Then, you can see this tab. [image]

Just click on the most recent coloured block and it will show you the commits.

Comment: Well this is awkward. I'm not seeing that tab http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/3967/UhVqhj.png

Comment: It's not a tab - look lower down the page

Comment: I'll take this as an answer thanks. I was lookng at an organization rather than a user. It's all new to me.